# How to set scroll for responsive table body

Tags: html, css-tables

I want view limited records in the table body if the limits exceeds it should have to scroll and the thead should remains fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer for this...

```
#custom-table th {
    text-align: left;
    width: 14.75%;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#custom-table td {
    width: 15%;
}
#custom-table tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#custom-table tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 158px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```